# Output xml with OCaml Format module

Tags: xml, ocaml, indentation

I'm trying to output XML with OCaml with indentation :

```
<document>
      <tag>
            <undertag/>
            <undertag/>
      </tag>
      <tag>
            <undertag/>
      </tag>
</document>
```

I'm trying with Format but I can't get the expected result...

```
Format.printf "@.";
  Format.printf
    "@[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @[<hv>@[<hv 2>(------------------------------------------------------------------------\
     @]@,)@]@]@,)@]@]@,)@]";
  Format.printf "@."
```

Does output :

```
(------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )
  )
)
```

But

```
fp "@.";
fp "@[<hv>@[<hv 2><document>";
fp "@[<hv>@[<hv 2><cfun>";
fp "@[<hv>@[<hv 2><cst/>@]@]";
fp "@]@,</cfun>@]";
fp "@]@,</document>@]";
fp "@.";
```

Where `fp = Format.printf` outputs `<document><cfun><cst/></cfun></document>` (all in one line !).

How should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Example using [xmlm](http://erratique.ch/software/xmlm) (intentionally procedural, use helper functions suitable for your case):

```
let out = Xmlm.make_output ~indent:(Some 4) (`Channel stdout) in
Xmlm.output out (`Dtd None);
Xmlm.output out (`El_start (("", "document"), []));
Xmlm.output out (`El_start (("", "tag"), []));
Xmlm.output out (`El_start (("", "undertag"), [(("", "id"), "1")]));
Xmlm.output out (`Data "data");
Xmlm.output out `El_end;
Xmlm.output out (`El_start (("", "undertag"), [(("", "id"), "2")]));
Xmlm.output out `El_end;
Xmlm.output out `El_end;
Xmlm.output out `El_end
```

Note the ***indent*** parameter.

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <tag>
        <undertag id="1">
            data
        </undertag>
        <undertag id="2"/>
    </tag>
</document>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather stick with the standard library, as it's the only thing I'm allowed. So I'd like to understand how Format works.

Answer (score 2):

A friend showed me a way to do it with vertical boxes.
The following outputs just fine : `@[<v 0>@,<xml>@,<document>@[<v 2>@,<tag>@[<v 2>@,<el>@,<el>@,<el>@]@,</tag>@]@,</document>@]`.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following using Format module:

Let's say you have this XML type,

```
type xml =
  | Tag of string * xml list
  | String of string

let tag name body = Tag (name, body)
```

Here's a pretty-printer for it:

```
let format, format_list = Format.(fprintf, pp_print_list)

let rec format_xml f = function
  | Tag (name, body) ->
      let format_body = format_list format_xml in
      format f "@[<hv 3><%s>@,%a@;<0 -3></%s>@]" name format_body body name
  | String text -> format f "%s" text
```

Here's a test case similar to yours:

```
let () =
  Format.set_margin 30;

  let xml = tag "document" [
    tag "tag" [tag "undertag" [String "hello"]];
    tag "tag" [tag "undertag" []];
  ] in
  format_xml Format.std_formatter xml
```

It prints the following:

```
<document>
   <tag>
      <undertag>
         hello
      </undertag>
   </tag>
   <tag>
      <undertag></undertag>
   </tag>
</document>
```

Another answer of mine has some more explanation about the format string that is used: [Boxes and XML in Format module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489419/boxes-and-xml-in-format-module/37188361#37188361)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@\n` to enforce line breaks. For `@,` or `@` the layout will try to fit as much in a line as possible -- but once it breaks a line, it will break subsequent lines in the same printing box. Experiment with it. See [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) and [guidelines](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/format.en.html).

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but it said, using @\n meant you didn't use the right boxes…

Comment: If you want a line break then use it. The above was a style comment.