# Boxes and XML in Format module

Tags: xml, ocaml

I would like to print an output using boxes and XML in [Format module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html).
An idea format is as follows:

```
<Events>
   <Event>
      <name> haha </name>
      <name> haha </name>
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <name> lili </name>
      <name> lili </name>
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <name> lolo </name>
      <name> lolo </name>
   </Event>
</Events>
```

At the moment my code is as follows, it does not print exactly what I expect (I omit to put the incorrect result here).

```
  (* in event.ml *)
  let print_name (fmt: formatter) (x: t) : unit =
    Format.open_tag "Name";
    Format.fprintf fmt "%s" (get_name x);
    Format.close_tag ()

  (* in events.ml *)
  let print (fmt: formatter) (x: t) : unit =
    let print (fmt: formatter) (x: t) : unit =
      List.iter
      (fun m ->
         Format.open_tag "Event";
         Format.fprintf fmt "@,@[<v 4>%a@,%a@," Event.print_name m 
                                     Event.print_name m; (* print twice *)
         Format.close_tag ();
         Format.fprintf fmt "@,@]")
      x
    in
    Format.open_tag "Events";
    Format.fprintf fmt "@,@[<v 4>%a@]@," print x;
    Format.close_tag ()

    (* in main.ml *)
    Format.fprintf Format.std_formatter "%a" Events.print x
```

I am not sure I understand well the box, especially when XML is involved. Does anyone know how to write these formats correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format is useful to print data with indentation, but its indentation algorithm is a bit tricky and is hard to simulate other indentation policies perfectly.  Maybe it is easier to handle indentation levels by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
let format, format_list = Format.(fprintf, pp_print_list) (* sorry, hate these cryptic names *)

type xml =
  | Tag of string * xml list
  | String of string

let rec format_xml f = function
  | Tag (name, body) ->
      let format_body = format_list format_xml in
      format f "@[<hv 3><%s>@,%a@;<0 -3></%s>@]" name format_body body name
  | String text -> format f "%s" text

let tag name body = Tag (name, body)
let name s = tag "name" [String s]

let () =
  Format.set_margin 50;

  let xml = tag "Events" [
    tag "Event" [
      name "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; name "b"; name "c";
    ];
    tag "Event" [name "a"; name "b"; name "c"];
    tag "Event" [name "a"; name "b"];
    tag "Event" [];
  ] in
  format_xml Format.std_formatter xml
```

Here's the output of the test-case above:

```
<Events>
   <Event>
      <name>
         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </name>
      <name>b</name>
      <name>c</name>
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <name>a</name>
      <name>b</name>
      <name>c</name>
   </Event>
   <Event><name>a</name><name>b</name></Event>
   <Event></Event>
</Events>
```

By tweaking the format string `@[<hv 3><%s>@,%a@;<0 -3></%s>@]`, you can either force it to lay out horizontally or vertically. To get the exact formatting that you specified, you would need the default tag box to be vertical `<v 3>`, but special-case your `name` tag box to be horizontal `<h>`. However, I decided to provide a more general example.

Let me explain. `@[<hv 3>` opens a box, which can alternate between horizontal `h` and vertical `v` layouts, depending on whether the contents of the box fit a single line, which in our case is 50 characters (see `Format.set_margin 50`). `3` in `@[<hv 3>` is the indentation level. `<%s>` is the opening XML tag, `</%s>`—closing. The opening tag is inside the box, but it is not indented, because indentation is introduced only on break hints like `@,`. We want the closing tag to *not* be indented, that's why we introduce a break hint `@;<0 -3>` which un-indents `-3` in case of vertical layout, but introduces `0` spaces in horizontal. Note that `Format.pp_print_list` which I'm using introduces break hints `@,` between list elements (by default).

Hope this is useful. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

You handle indentation using boxes. To realize this indentation you need to use boxes as follows (parens delineate boxes):

```
((<tag>contents)</tag>)
```

Note how boxes and tags are *differently* nested.  This technique is used in **[Gasoline](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline)** see:

- [testsuite](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline/tree/master/testsuite/trip-trap/authorkit) for usage examples
- [implementation](https://github.com/michipili/gasoline/blob/master/author/gasoline_Author_SGML.ml)

Note that the *authorkit* from **Gasoline** is useful for writing simple ad-hoc *SGML* files but in advanced caes, libraries from the **ocsigen** projects are probably more useful (but harder to use).